# CSS: Is it possible to style default check-boxes with CSS only to get this result?

Tags: html, css

I have such a PS design of check-boxes. Is it possible to get it on screen by styling a default check-box with CSS? Or do I have to create some custom check-boxes with elements that can be styled (`div`s, etc)?

[image]

Comment: you can create it with divs, question is will they behave like checkboxes? No, so you need to style checkboxes only

Comment: @NaeemShaikh, So, can I style default checkboxes to get as they are on the picture? I know, I can style borders and shadows, but can I get the same check-marks with CSS?